# R: How to use row-wise apply with individual columns as input variables?

Tags: r

I create a list with all unique combinations of two columns in a data.table.

Based on all unique combinations in this list I want to take samples from a data.table.

I already wrote a function for this and I know that I could use a for-loop or a foreach-loop.
How could the funcion in the following be used with "apply" or one of its variations?

Thank you very much :-)

MWE:

```
dt <- data.table(filename = c("a", "b", "c", "c", "a"), class = c(1,2,1,1,4), var = c(1,2,3,4,5))
unique_combinations <- unique(dt[, c("filename", "class")])

take_samples <- function(dt, filename, class, n) {
  dt %>%
    .[filename==filename & class==class] %>%
    sample_n(size=n, replace = FALSE)

  #TBD: append result to other data.table
}

# How to do the following call automatically for every unique combination using apply?
take_samples(dt, unique_combinations$filename[0], unique_combinations$class[0], 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need groupby:

```
n <- 1
dt[,.SD[sample(.N, size = n, replace = T)], .(filename, class)]
```

**Explanation**

- Grouping by `.(filename, class)` will take unique combination of the two columns.
- `.SD` contains the grouped dataframe.

Here's the ouptut looks like:

```
   filename class var
1:        a     1   1
2:        b     2   2
3:        c     1   4
4:        a     4   5
```

Comment: Thanks, this samples columns instead of rows. I would like to have n samples (= rows) of each unique filename and class combination.

Comment: Are you sure? I just checked the result, check the edit.

Comment: check the answer now, fixed it.

Comment: Sorry, I was not precise enough. In reality my table consists a lot of columns. Try it with n=1 and adding another column like: dt2 <- data.table(filename = c("a", "b", "c", "c", "a"), class = c(1,2,1,1,4), var = c(1,2,3,4,5), var = c(1,2,3,4,5))